# Why do the bivariate vectors $(X_t, X_s)$ and $(X_s, X_t)$ from strictly stationary $X_t$ not have the same distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, time-series

from homework I got some weeks ago, we were asked if the bivariate vectors of $(X_t, X_s)$ and $(X_s, X_t)$ from strictly stationary Time Series$X_t$ do not have the same distribution.
I thought they should, but the solution is that they do not.

Unfortunately, the solution only says False.

Can someone explain to me why?

The reason I thought it must be was almost trivial, since for strict stationarity I thought that $X_t, X_s \sim F$ for some distribution $F$.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a time series such that $X_t$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,3\}$ and $X_{t+1}=\operatorname{mod}(X_t,3)+1$, i.e. you set $X_{t+1}=X_t+1$ if $X_t\in\{1,2\}$ and $X_{t+1}=1$ if $X_t=3$.

Then $(X_t,X_{t+1})$ is uniformly distributed on $\{(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)\}$ but $(X_{t+1},X_t)$ is uniformly distributed on $\{(1,3), (2,1), (3,2)\}$.

Comment: Hi Will, thank you very much for answering.
I am having a little trouble with the example, hope you allow some questions.
Are the $X_t$ discrete with equal probability on $\{1,2,3\}$? If yes, wouldn't that violate the strict stationarity since $X_t$ and $X_{t+1}$ then don't seem to have the same distribution?

Comment: Yes the $X_t$ are discrete with equal probability on 1, 2 and 3. $X_t$ and $X_{t+1}$ do have the same distribution because $\mathbb P(X_{t+1}=1)=\mathbb P(X_t=3)=\frac13$, $\mathbb P(X_{t+1}=2)=\mathbb P(X_t=1)=\frac13$ and $\mathbb P(X_{t+1}=3)=\mathbb P(X_t=2)=\frac13$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I get it now, what an interesting example!